# How to calculate robot hand positions using Roll, Pitch angles

Tags: robotic-arm, forward-kinematics

i want to calculate humanoid robot hand position with given shoulder roll, pitch angles and elbow roll angle.

I'm able to calculate elbow position using rotation matrix which includes shoulder angles.

But i dont know how to calculate hand position using elbow position and elbow roll angle.

Can you propose a method to calculate hand position?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Are you asking how to calculate the forward kinematics of a humanoid arm.  Is your arm 3 DOF?  (2 in shoulder and 1 in elbow)?

Comment: Yes. I'm asking how to calculate the forward kinematics of a humanoid. The arm 3 Dof. 2 in shoulder and 1 in elbow.

Comment: Are you familiar with this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_kinematics or is there something special about the humanoid setup you're using?  If you have not heard of DH then there is a good online course on robotics from Stanford that goes into the details.